# Remove product attribute automatically

Tags: magento2

hi i have a custom module where am adding custom attribute using the code below.

```
 <?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;
    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
    
    /**
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
    {
        /**
         * EAV setup factory
         *
         * @var EavSetupFactory
         */
        private $eavSetupFactory;
    
        /**
         * Init
         *
         * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
         */
        public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
        {
            $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
         */
        public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    
            /**
             * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
             */
    
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                    'no_free_shipping',
                    [
                        'group' => 'General',
                        'type' => 'int',
                        'backend' => '',
                        'frontend' => '',
                        'label' => 'no_free_shipping',
                        'input' => 'boolean',
                        'class' => '',
                        'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean::class,
                        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                        'visible' => true,
                        'required' => false,
                        'user_defined' => false,
                        'default' => '1',
                        'searchable' => false,
                        'filterable' => false,
                        'comparable' => false,
                        'visible_on_front' => false,
                        'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                        'unique' => false,
                        'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,bundle'
                    ]
                );
    
                $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                    'no_flat_rate',
                    [
                        'group' => 'General',
                        'type' => 'int',
                        'backend' => '',
                        'frontend' => '',
                        'label' => 'no_flat_rate',
                        'input' => 'boolean',
                        'class' => '',
                        'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean::class,
                        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                        'visible' => true,
                        'required' => false,
                        'user_defined' => false,
                        'default' => '1',
                        'searchable' => false,
                        'filterable' => false,
                        'comparable' => false,
                        'visible_on_front' => false,
                        'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                        'unique' => false,
                        'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,bundle'
                    ]
                );
    
    
                $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                    'no_table_rate',
                    [
                        'group' => 'General',
                        'type' => 'int',
                        'backend' => '',
                        'frontend' => '',
                        'label' => 'no_table_rate',
                        'input' => 'boolean',
                        'class' => '',
                        'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean::class,
                        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                        'visible' => true,
                        'required' => false,
                        'user_defined' => false,
                        'default' => '1',
                        'searchable' => false,
                        'filterable' => false,
                        'comparable' => false,
                        'visible_on_front' => false,
                        'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                        'unique' => false,
                        'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,bundle'
                    ]
                );
            }
        }
```

what i want is when user removes the module or uninstalled it then these attributes should automatically removed from the catalog under add product section.
i know about using **unistall.php** but it only works with the module installed using composer. so am looking for a solution other than this.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

No other way available to remove that attribute while removing /uninstalled the extension except `bin/magento module:uninstall`

Comment: but how to tackle the case the module is installed manually? it become hassle for the user to remove those attributes manually and most of the developers including me prefer to install module manually

Comment: there has to be away to tackle this thing

Comment: So far at my knowledge, No way available. There are some cases, you can do what you want.

Comment: no problem thanks for the rply am still looking in to this will post an ans if i got some success

Comment: in the module, place a REAME file and in this file put a command line that triggers the php script that will uninstall these product attributes

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy i think it still become more like manual do we have any other way rather than this

Comment: @AmitBera is this command works for extensions installed manually? in one of my module, I wrote uninstall script to delete custom attribute created by the module but I found that uninstall.php scripts run for those modules which have been installed through composer

Comment: yes@WaqarAli that is what i had mentioned in my question

Answer (score 0):

Disable Or delete your custom module, than go to Databse and search attribute code in  last entries in these tables and delete them.

1. eav_attribute
2. catalog_eav_attribute (remember attribute id form 'eav_attribute' table)
   [image]

[image]

Comment: that is more technical and if your client is non technical then he wont be able to perform this